# C# LINQ to rank time series values on a daily basis => partition by date, then rank by value (largest to smallest)

Tags: c#, linq, ranking, time-series

I have a set of about 2000 separate time-series in the form of `SortedList<DateTime,double>`. Each series corresponds to the daily liquidity for a given security. I would like to created a daily ranking of these values. Were I to do this with for loops, I would do the following:

1. Create a new empty time-series [date, (int)rank] for each security to hold its rank on a given day. This can be in the form of a `SortedList<DateTime,double>`.
2. Created a list of all the unique dates (not every securities' time-series has a value for every date.)
3. For each unique date, loop through each of the securities' daily  liquidity time-series to determine if it had a value for that date.
4. If it did, add the securities name, and value to the daily ranking array [SecName, liquidity Value].
5. Sort the array from largest to smallest (rank 1 = largest value).
6. For each security (secName) in the array, add the date and the securities' rank to its time-series (created in step 1).

Simply, this is a daily ranking of liquidity from largest to smallest. I can get linq to pull the data from the objects and group by date, but the rest is beyond my linq skills.

Any linq masters care to give this a shot?

A simplified version of the object structure is outlined below.

*Note: I have intentionally created one date (2011,01,18) where the values (30) are the same. In this case, a sub-ranking by symbol name is acceptable. So they would be ranked... 1st 6753 JT, 2nd 6754 JT. 6752 JT does not have a value for that date, so it would not be included.*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Ranking_Query
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // created an instance of the datasource and add 3 securities to it
            Datasource ds = new Datasource() { Name = "test" };

            ds.securities.Add("6752 JT", new Security() { 
                timeSeries = new Dictionary<string, SortedList<DateTime, double>>() {
                    { "liquidity", new SortedList<DateTime, double>() { 
                        {new DateTime(2011,01,15),30},
                        {new DateTime(2011,01,16),20},
                        {new DateTime(2011,01,17),10} } } }
            });

            ds.securities.Add("6753 JT", new Security()
            {
                timeSeries = new Dictionary<string, SortedList<DateTime, double>>() {
                    { "liquidity", new SortedList<DateTime, double>() { 
                        {new DateTime(2011,01,15),20},
                        {new DateTime(2011,01,16),30},
                        {new DateTime(2011,01,17),20},
                        {new DateTime(2011,01,18),30} } } }
            });

            ds.securities.Add("6754 JT", new Security()
            {
                timeSeries = new Dictionary<string, SortedList<DateTime, double>>() {
                    { "liquidity", new SortedList<DateTime, double>() { 
                        {new DateTime(2011,01,16),10},
                        {new DateTime(2011,01,17),30},
                        {new DateTime(2011,01,18),30} } } }
            });


        }

        class Datasource
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, Security> securities = new Dictionary<string, Security>();
        }

        class Security
        {
            public string symbol { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, SortedList<DateTime, double>> timeSeries;
        }

    }
}
```

The output using a foreach loop like this...

```
    foreach (var sec in rankingsBySymbol)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sec.Key);
        foreach (var secRank in sec)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  {0} value {1} rank {2}",secRank.Date, secRank.Value, secRank.Rank);
        }
    }
```

Should be as follows...

```
6752 JT
  1/15/2011 12:00:00 AM value 30 rank 1
  1/16/2011 12:00:00 AM value 20 rank 2
  1/17/2011 12:00:00 AM value 10 rank 3
6753 JT
  1/15/2011 12:00:00 AM value 20 rank 2
  1/16/2011 12:00:00 AM value 30 rank 1
  1/17/2011 12:00:00 AM value 20 rank 2
  1/18/2011 12:00:00 AM value 30 rank 1
6754 JT
  1/16/2011 12:00:00 AM value 10 rank 3
  1/17/2011 12:00:00 AM value 30 rank 1
  1/18/2011 12:00:00 AM value 30 rank 2
```

Note: The final output does not need to include the initial value used to calculate the ranking, just the date and rank. I have included it because it make it easier to understand the initial question.

Comment: the desired output is not clear, IMO...maybe add example output matching that?

Comment: @Marc: I have edited the above query to include an example of matching output. I hope this make the question clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data structures aren't terribly clear, but I *think* you want something like:

```
// Initial query just to get a sequence of { Symbol, Date, Value } entries.
var entries = from securityPair in ds.securities
              from valuation in securityPair.Value.timeSeries["liquidity"]
              select new { Symbol = securityPair.Key,
                           Date = valuation.Key,
                           valuation.Value };

// Now do the grouping, sorting and ranking
var groupedByDate = from entry in entries
                    group entry by entry.Date into date
                    select date.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
                               .ThenBy(x => x.Symbol)
                               // Use the overload of Select which includes the
                               // index within the sequence (*after* sorting)
                               .Select((x, index) => new {
                                    x.Symbol,
                                    x.Value,
                                    x.Date,
                                    Rank = index + 1,
                                });

// Now group by symbol again
var rankingsBySymbol = groupedByDate.SelectMany(day => day)
                                    .ToLookup(tuple => tuple.Symbol,
                                              tuple => new { tuple.Date,
                                                             tuple.Value,
                                                             tuple.Rank });
```

This will build you a lookup by symbol, where each symbol will have a list of results (in date order) of the symbol's value and rank for that date.

At least, that's the plan. I haven't tested this at all...

Comment: Jon, thank you for the response. Sorry about the lack of clarity. I now see that I was missing the creation of a security, date, value sequence. Overall, I understand what you have done here. However, I am not really clear as to what the middle query's select is doing.  I will try it now.

Comment: @Andre: The middle bit is grouping by date, and then ordering the results within that date, so that we can get the ranking. I *hope* that's what you were after :)

Comment: Small point:  `security.timeSeries` should read  `security.Value.timeSeries` and `security.symbol` should read `security.Value.symbol`

Comment: @Jon: Indeed, that is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: @Andre: You seem to have the security symbol in two places - as the key for the key/value pair *and* within the security itself... but in your sample code you're never actually setting it within the security. I meant to get it from the key of the key/value pair - will edit.

Comment: @Jon: It run precisely as I wanted after incorporating the edits you made. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: To extract the results (took me a moment to get this right)
            `foreach (var sec in rankingsBySymbol)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sec.Key);
                foreach (var secRank in sec)
                    Console.WriteLine("  {0} value {1} rank {2}",secRank.Date, secRank.Value, secRank.Rank);
            }`

Comment: @Andre: My pleasure. I'm somewhat amazed that a relatively complex query written on a bus worked with only minor tweaks. Yay LINQ :)

Comment: @Jon: "Yay LINQ!" ... but also a testament to the author's skill. This sample will go a looooong way. I also need to do daily Z-scores, percentile, and % of daily sum calculation. Mathematically, they are all trivial, but I needed the query framework.

Comment: @Andre: One thing to note is that this is relatively inefficient, as it doesn't take into account the fact that you've got the incoming data sorted by date already. A hand-rolled solution could probably perform quicker... but would take a lot longer to write. Hopefully that won't be an issue for you though :)